# Vector geometry problem that uses projection but I am unclear on how to solve.

Tags: geometry

I have another problem I am struggling with so bear with me here.

The Problem:
Let A = (1,1,2) and let B be the point on the plane 4x+y-3z=1 closest to A. To find B, let C = (0,1,0) which lies on the same plane as B. Find $\overrightarrow{AB}.$

What I've done. Knowing the normal vector for the plane, we get (4,1,-3) which we'll call P. I tried to calculate the projection on A onto B using A-B = ((A *(dot product) P)/||P||^2)*P which resulted in (-4/26, -1/16,3/26). Then using some substitution we get B = A - the projection of A onto B. Which I calculated to be (15/13, 27/26, 49/26). This does not seem right to me, the numbers are too messy and I don't see how to use C if we can just do vector projection to find it easily. I may be misinterpreting the question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope this follows the rules better than my last question.

Comment: I do not understand what $PV$ is.

Comment: Oh Sorry! I meant to write AB instead of PV. My bad

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would have done it.

The line $P$ in the direction of the vector $(4,1,-3)$ and passing through the point
$A = (1,1,2)$ has a parametric form

$$(x,y,z) = (1+4t, 1+1t, 2-3t)$$

It will intersect the plane when $t$ satisfies the equation

\begin{align}
   4(1+4t) + 1(1+t) - 3(2-3t) &= 0 \\
   26t - 1 &= 0 \\
   t &= \dfrac{1}{26} \\
\end{align}

and so, $B = \frac{1}{26}(30, 27, 49)$

Comment: I think you meant $(4, 1, -3)$.

Comment: @Mankind - Thanks. Fixed it.